# reCaptcha - formulário enviado é validado?

Tags: html, jsp, recaptcha

Estou implementando o reCaptcha, a caixa com o checkbox para o usuário clicar e confirmar que não é um robô está sendo apresentada, porém tenho dúvidas se realmente esta funcionando, pois estou usando:

```
"... if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "")..."
```

e não sei se algum robô poderia burlar isso, já que não estou analisando a resposta que a API do Google devolve, apenas verifico se existe retorno.

Obs: esta página é HTML, mas também implementarei o reCaptcha em jsp.

Segue código:

```js
function logar(){
 if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "")
  {
       alert("Você não clicou no reCAPTCHA, por favor, faça!")
       return false;
  } else {
   document.login.submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt' async defer></script>


<form class="form-inline" role="form" name="login" action="loginController.do" method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Usuario: <input type="text" name="login">
    senha <input type="text" name="senha">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XX_chave_XX"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="logar()" >Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Se o usuário não colocar marcar corretamente a caixa do reCaptcha, o retorno não será uma string vazia, da forma que você ta comparando.
Mas sim um array vazio.
Logo, você deve verificar da seguinte forma:

```
var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(v.length == 0)
{
    alert("Você não clicou no reCAPTCHA, por favor, faça!")
    return false;
} else {
     document.login.submit();
 }
```

Espero ter ajudado.